# Analytic signal of the Dirac delta function

Tags: hilbert-spaces, signal-processing, dirac-delta, integral-transforms

Does anyone know of any derivations of the analytic signal of the Dirac delta function? I suppose that it can be found by first working from the definition of the Hilbert transform, since the analytic representation of a real-valued function is the analytic signal, comprising the original function and its Hilbert transform? Appreciate any insight.

Comment: The result is $1/(\pi t)$, provided here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Relationship_with_the_Fourier_transform

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any sources that show a derivation or proof of this result?

Answer (score 0):

The Hilbert transform is defined as
$$ H[u](t) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{ u(t+\tau) - u(t-\tau)}{\pi \tau} d\tau. $$
Inserting the Dirac delta for $u$, we have
$$  H[\delta(t)](t) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{\delta(\tau+t)-\delta(\tau-t)}{\pi \tau} d\tau.$$
Now using the sifting property of the Delta function, we obtain
$$ H[\delta(t)](t) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}  \Big[\frac{\Theta(\tau+t)}{\pi t} +\frac{\Theta(\tau-t)}{\pi t}\Big]\Bigg|_\infty^\epsilon \\
= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}   \Big[\frac{\Theta(\epsilon+t)-1}{\pi t} + \frac{\Theta(\epsilon-t)-1}{\pi t}\Big]\\
= \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}   \frac{\Theta(-\epsilon-t)+\Theta(t-\epsilon)}{\pi t}\\
= \frac{1}{\pi t},$$
thereby arriving at the solution on wikipedia

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Is Θ the heaviside function?

Comment: Yes, the integral of a Delta function.